# Find zero crossing of sampled function

Tags: matlab

I have a vector :

```
d1 = [10 7 4 1 -2 -3 4 5 6 1 -2 -0.1]
```

I want to detect when diff cut the x-axis, it means when diff(d1) = 0 to have the changement of variation.

NB: the x-axis = `0:1:12`

Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: You don't want to use `diff` as the nave of your vector, as it is a name of a [different function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html).

Comment: Especially in this context... its a function which is highly likely to be used here!